# How to align text to center in Accordion Component of Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

This is my Accordion component:

[image: Basic Accordion Component]

I want the above component to look like this:

[image: Center Aligned Accordion]

I want to make those headings (Accordion 1, Accordion 2) center aligned. But I'm unable to do it.

Please help, below is the code from Material-UI website:

```
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion disabled>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3a-content"
          id="panel3a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Disabled Accordion</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Material-Ui Component Link: https://next.material-ui.com/components/accordion/#basic-accordion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this heading come in the center, there is a class "*MuiAccordionSummary-content*".

By-default, it is **display: flex**

Now, the only property you need to add to this class named as *MuiAccordionSummary-content*
**justify-content: center;**

To override the css, please visit the link :
[Style Customisation in Material UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

At times, we have to OVERRIDE the default behaviour of the components or say override the styles as per our requirements.

If you don't want to directly override it, use the inlinestyle or a specific classname like we do for normal css.

Answer (score 3):

## Code

First we create our styles using the `useStyles()` API:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  content: {
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Next, in every `AccordionSummary` component, we apply the styles using the `classes` prop like the following:

```
<AccordionSummary
  classes={{ content: classes.content }}  // <-- Add this line
  /* ... */
>
```

[image: Edit on Code Sandbox]

## Explanation

With reference to the example from the [documentation on customizing components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#using-the-dev-tools), we open Chrome DevTools to inspect the accordion:

[image: DevTools screenshot]

Note that the class name of the content container is `MuiAccordionSummary-content`. This means we can apply styling to `AccordionSummary` component using the following format:

```
<AccordionSummary classes={{ content: XXXX }} />
```

Therefore, we define a style object called `content` using `makeStyles` API, then we use this object to style every `AccordionSummary` component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Material 5, SX Solution if you don't want to use classes;

```
<AccordionSummary>
   <Typography align="center" sx={{width: '100%'}}>Accordion 1</Typography>
</AccordionSummary>
```

So, when you cover whole area with Typography component (which, you are already using), you can use Typography's align prop.