# Center typography inside material UI accordion

Tags: css, material-ui

I am using Material UI and I would like to center the text inside the Typography. On the dev tools I change the `<AccordionSummary>` to `'grid'` and it works, but I am not able to do it on the code:

```
<Accordion sx={{ background: "#141821" }}>
    <AccordionSummary>
        <Typography sx={{ color: `${colors.grey[100]}`, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}>Staff members on vacation</Typography>
    </AccordionSummary>
    <AccordionDetails>
        <Table>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center"> Employee</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center"> Start Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center"> End Date</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                        Michael 
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                        21-11-2023
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                        28-11-2023
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: please provide a full working example for this.

Comment: For some reason at the beginning did not show the complete code, now it does. @jessman5

Comment: found this one which helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703172/how-to-align-text-to-center-in-accordion-component-of-material-ui